# ReactJS - Using jQuery to load data from a server

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS from https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

And there is one example for downloading JSON data from a server that I don't really understand.
I have this method:

```
loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
```

But why is there `.bind(this)` what is the purpose of it ? I have tried to look it up in jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/bind/) but somehow I see no connection between using it as shown in the documentation and how I used in with React.

Comment: [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) ([Also.](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/23/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the variable scoping on JavaScript. Since you're inside a function there, like that:

```
success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }
```

Your "`this`" will refer to the scope inside the success function. When you do a `.bind(this)` after the function, it tells the JS that you want to use the outer reference for this. In your case, the scoping for the outer function "`loadCommentsFromServer`"

Also I'd recomend you further reading:
http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/23/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/

Answer (score 1):

The bind method allows you to change the context of a function.

Here is a little example to understand bind()

```
var myPie = {
  love : 'FULL'
};

function doILove(){
  console.log(this.love);
}

doILove(); // returns undefined
doILove().bind(myPie); // returns 'FULL'
```

Actually, your code is to call the `this.props.url` url, we expect `json` data from the server, if we success we execute the `success` function, else if we failed we execute the `error` function.